# Proving an Inequality Involving a Differentiable Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

There is this problem

> Let $f$ be a real valued differentiable function on $[0,\inf)$ s.t. $f(0)=1$ and $3 \leq f'(x) \leq 4$ for all $x  \in [0,\inf)$. Prove there exist a constant $c$ s.t. $$1 \leq \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} \leq c \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall \; x \geq 0$$

I am trying it as follows (Which I totally not sure is right or not),

starting from $$ 3 \leq f'(x) \leq 4 $$ $$3 \leq \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \leq 4 \implies 3 \leq \frac{f(x)-1}{x} \leq 4$$ because $x \geq 0$, s0

$$3x \leq {f(x)-1} \leq 4x \implies 3x+1 \leq f(x) \leq 4x+1$$ $$ \frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}} \leq \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}} \leq \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}}$$

$(3x+1)^2=9x^2+6x+1 \geq 9x^2+1$ because $x \geq 0$ gives

$$ 1 \leq\frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}} \leq \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}} \leq \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}} \implies 1 \leq \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}} \leq \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2 +1}}$$,

I got one side, but I don't know what to do next....

Comment: Nice work!. I think you've basically solved it, to be honest. The important idea is to understand that $f$ is constrained into this "envelope" between $3x + 1$ and $4x + 1$. All you have left to do now is to show that $\frac{4x + 1}{\sqrt{9x^2 + 1}}$ is bounded above on $[0, \infty)$ (you can tell you'll have to show this, because $4x + 1$ satisfies the hypothesis!). There's not anything particularly "clever" you have to do to show this - it would suffice for instance to prove that it tends to a finite limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: However if you'd prefer to use some cute algebra to get an inequality, you could start by writing it as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2 + 1}} + \frac{4x}{\sqrt{9x^2 + 1}}$ and then bound those two terms separately. (think about decreasing the denominator..)

Comment: okay, thinking this way, one factor having $4x$ in the numerator is bounded by $4/3$ and the other one is by $1/3x$. But now again, $1/3x$ is not bounded near 0. What to do in this scenario?

Comment: There is a reason I split it into two terms. Try graphing the functions $9x^2 + 1$ and $\frac{1}{9x^2 + 1}$ and see if that gives you any ideas for how to show this is bounded!

Comment: ahh Okay, $\sqrt{9x^2+1}$ has the min value at $x=0$, and thus, its reciprocal will have the max value at $x=0$, which means, it is bounded by 1. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed! If you like, you can write a short answer to this post, explaining in your own words what the solution was, and then accept it.

Comment: just one more thing, From where I have started ( $3 \leq f'(x) \leq 4$ )  and in the next step, I took off the limit and used the definition of derivative at $x=0$,  is that come from the Mean Value Theorem on $[0,x]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

So, After the discussion (in comments) with [Izaak van Dongen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/473276/izaak-van-dongen), I came up with the following solution:

After this step, $$ 1 \leq \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} \leq \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} $$

This question is now reduced to show only that the function $\frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}$ is bounded by some constant. And to prove that, let do the following:

$$\frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} = \frac{4x}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}$$

Now on the right side, we got 2 functions, lets check both separately,

1. $\frac{4x}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}= \frac{4x}{x\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$ which is now bounded by $\frac{4}{3}$ for all $x\in[0,\inf)$.
2. And for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}$, note that $\sqrt{9x^2+1}$ take its minimum value at $x=0$, which means $\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}$ will have its maximum value at $x=0$, thus put it in that function, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{9(0)^2+1}}=1$, thus $\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} \leq 1$ for all $x \in [0,\inf)$.

Thus combining the above two points, we have $$ \frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} \leq \frac{4}{3} + 1 = \frac{7}{3} $$

And, Hence, we have  $$ 1 \leq \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{9x^2+1}} \leq \frac{7}{3} $$